# when create table inside database using db2 i get error SQL0007N?

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw, influxdb-2

I work on db2 database . I get error when create table inside database
but I don't know how to solve this error .

I create table from db2 command windows Administrator

text file `TestTables.sql` contain query need executed by db2 as below

```
Create TABLE books (id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL , author VARCHAR(255)  NOT  NULL , title VARCHAR(255)   NOT  NULL , isbn INT  NULL , PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

what I try

```
db2 => tvf C:\Users\MBR\Desktop\TestTables.sql
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0007N  The statement was not processed because a character that is not
supported in SQL statements was included in the SQL statement.  Invalid
character: "\".  Text preceding the invalid character: "tvf C:".
SQLSTATE=42601
```

so How to solve this error please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks as if calling the .sql file by specifying the whole path ("C:\Users\MBR\Desktop\TestTables.sql") is wrong.

```
Invalid character: "\".  Text preceding the invalid character: "tvf C:".
```

Try to change current directory to Desktop, and then call the file *without* folder name.

```
c:\temp>cd c:\users\mbr\desktop
```

[Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=clp-options) says

> Read from Input File Option (-f):
>
> The -f filename option tells the command line processor to read input from a specified file, instead of from standard input. Filename is an absolute or relative file name can include the directory path to the file. **If the directory path is not specified, the current directory is used**.